# Convert a text to matrix in Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark

these are my data:

```
0,2 # Spark is more intelligent about how it operates on data. 
1,5 # it always looks to limit how much work it has to do. 
2,3 # Sometimes a data analyst just record for the Chicago store.
...
```

and i want to extract one matrix like below from these data:

```
0 2
1 5
2 3
...
```

and i've tried:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("prep").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sample1 = sc.textFile("data.txt")
    val cnt = sample1.count()
    val tt = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](cnt.toInt,1)
    var doc_val = sample1.flatMap({ (line) =>
      val tuple = line.split("#")
      val ss = tuple(0).split(",")
      val docid = ss(0).toInt
      val docscore = ss(2)
      tt(docid, 0) = docscore
    })
    println(tt)
}
```

but it couldn't compile , 
What's problem?

Comment: "Couldn't compile" - needs more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't compile because DenseMatrix does not take type parameters. Same as the other data structures from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg` it can only store `Double` values.

Same thing applies when you use PySpark. Data structures from `pyspark.mllib.linalg` store `numpy.float64` values.

Another problem is your attempt to set value of tt. All data structures from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg` (in PyPspark `pyspark.mllib.linalg`) are immutable.

Finally you shouldn't use `flatMap` to only to get some side effects. `flatMap` has both a clean semantics and rather specific signature:

```
def flatMap[U](f: T => TraversableOnce[U]) RDD[U]
```

If it was possible to modify a `DenseMatrix` you should use `foreach` method. Since it is not one way to approach the problem is to use a simple map:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrices

val cnt = sample1.count()
val vals = sample1.map {
    case rowIdAndScore(rowId, rowScore) => rowScore.toDouble
}

val tt = Matrices.dense(cnt, 1, vals.collect())
```

On a side note another possible problem is an usage of `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix`. I assume you load your data as an `RDD` for a reason. If so, it make sense to use one of the distributed data structures from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed` instead. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix}

val sample1 = sc.textFile("data.txt")
val rowIdAndScore = """^(\d)+\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*#.*$""".r

val rows = sample1.map {case rowIdAndScore(rowId, rowScore) => {
    IndexedRow(rowId.toLong, Vectors.dense(rowScore.toDouble))
}}

val tt = new IndexedRowMatrix(rows)
```

Assuming this question is related to [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214250/convert-a-text-to-matrix-in-scala-and-spark) you can avoid at least a part of string processing by mapping directly without creating an intermediate RDD.